# Error making an MySQL event

Tags: mysql, events

I've got a MySQL table that needs to be emptied every midnight due to information in there being used for sessions.
I've tried to create a MySQL event after turning on the global parameter but it gives me a Syntax error as soon as I want to create one.
[This is the error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVKLt.png)

```
CREATE EVENT delete_messages_at_midnight 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
DO DELETE FROM t_choices; 
delimeter;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimeter' at line 4

Due to me being new here and having lower than 10 rep I can't post images unfortunantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the semicolon after:

```
t_choices;
```

and simply try

```
delimiter
CREATE EVENT delete_messages_at_midnight 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   DO DELETE FROM t_choices
delimeter ;
```

or like this:

```
delimiter
|
CREATE EVENT delete_messages_at_midnight 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   DO DELETE FROM t_choices;
|
delimeter ; //Put a space between delimiter and semicolon
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunantly im still getting an error after I enter the query.


SQL-query:

EVENT delete_messages_at_midnight ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY DO DELETE FROM t_choices delimiter;

MySQL meldt: Documentatie

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EVENT delete_messages_at_midnight 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE() ' at line 1

Comment: @Xianchu:- Did you try to add a space between `delimeter ;`

Comment: Yes. It just says this now:Error.
Nothing else, no specific error just the word error..